# How do I write rexexp with an exclusion and inclusion at the same time?

Tags: r, regex, case

I want to extract this patter:

```
data %>% mutate(type = case_when(
  grepl("\\b(channel(s)?|multichannel|multeple|multiple|multi)\\b", words) && !grepl("\\bsingle\\b") == TRUE ~ "multichannel",
  TRUE ~ '_other'
  ))
```

It should catch multi channel, but exclude single channel.
But it doesn't work: it didn't catch any multichannel.

How to solve it?

Comment: Maybe change the `&&` to `&` ?